# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Web Application (Forms) Edit & Continue doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Just ran update 2 for VS 2015 and the "Edit and Continue" on my web application (c# web forms) does not seem to work anymore. It is checked in Options > Debugging > General.

Anyone else having this problem? Or maybe i'm not setting it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems I got the "Edit and Continue" like feature to work by pressing **Ctrl + F5**. This allows to run the project without debugging (keeps IIS express running) which is what I was looking to do.

Still not sure why starting and stopping debug doesn't keep IIS express running in the background after running update 2?